# How to display an external image or graph in my existing Angular 6 application?

Tags: angular, typescript, graph, angular6

I am trying to build an application which displays an external graph hosted in a different server. I am providing the url in the script and trying to display it in my component. But nothing is getting displayed. Instead I am getting an error like this :-

app.component.ts:28 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response .... with MIME type text/html.

I came across some other posts where ComponentFactoryResolver has been used to dynamically load a component but could not really implement that solution.

A working code snippet would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can't display any image in your angular app.
Because back end server must be enabled cors.
But problem is that we can't enable cors in front end.
So this is impossible I think.

Answer (score 0):

CORS (cross origin requests) on your server side must be enabled in order to be allowed doing this.

Comment: Thank you @sancelot. I will give that a try.